# IE8 Support for D3 using Aight

Tags: javascript, d3.js, internet-explorer-8

I have tried the supporting libraries r2d3 and Aight for D3, but neither of them have them worked. In the D3 documents Aight is recommended (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki#browser-support)

> For IE8, the compatibility library Aight is recommended.

Here is the Demo link, that I have created using "Aight" (https://github.com/shawnbot/aight) . This is not working in IE8.

[JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/kuragaxu/2/edit)

Please suggest a correct supporting library for D3, along with a working example in jsbin or jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 1):

Take the HTML code out of JSBin and paste it into a `aightd3.html` file via Notepad.  When you open it in IE8 it will render fine (with a few exceptions, like opacity and timer speed)